# Reason of an SSL error in Swift 2 and iOS9

Tags: swift, ssl-certificate, ios9, nsurlsession

I got the following error while establishing an HTTPs (Secure HTTP) connection in Swift 2 and iOS9:

```
 [NSLocalizedDescription: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion: Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey: 3, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x175bc540>, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=<CFArray 0x175bd200 [0x3c11cca8]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : <cert(0x175bbf90) s: example.com i: example.com>
)}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey: -9802, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey: https://example.com.com:pppp/, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey: (
    "<cert(0x175bbf90) s: example.com i: example.com.com>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey: 0, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey: <SecTrustRef: 0x175bc540>, NSErrorFailingURLKey: https://example.com:pppp/]
```

I want to know the exact exact reason of this issue and how can I find exact reason of an SSL issue?

I got the following output from curl command:

[image]

I also did the following changes in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>example.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Still I am getting error in app and not able to connect to server.

**Please anyone can give me an example or link for implementing SSL pinning with self signed certificate in iOS 9 and Xcode 7.**

Comment: most likely to the changes apple made in iOS 9, by default it refuses connections to server not using TLS 1.2

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin In my case sever is using TLS 1.2

Comment: It seems that your client certificates aren't working for TLS 1.2.

Comment: @Christian, I have edited my question.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I have edited my question.